# "errorMessage": "Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function'",

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I was creating a bucket with below code. Is it compulsory to write lambda_function(event,context) while doing anything?

Code is below

```
import json
import boto3

BUCKET_NAME = 'ly_2020_s3'
def s3_client():
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    return s3

def create_bucket(bucket_name):
    return s3_client().create_bucket(
        Bucket=bucket_name,CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint':'eu-central-1'})

if __name__=='__main__':
    create_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lambda handler function is required:

- [AWS Lambda function handler in Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html)

For example:

```
import json
import boto3

BUCKET_NAME = 'lilly_2020_s3'

def s3_client():

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    return s3

def create_bucket(bucket_name):

    return s3_client().create_bucket(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstrain':'eu-central-1'})

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    bucket_name = 'some-backet-name'
    create_bucket(bucket_name)
```

Comment: LocationConstrain to LocationConstraint

Comment: @Nons Sorry. I'm not sure what do you mean? The error was about missing `lambda_handler`, not about `LocationConstrain`.

Comment: your answer is working  fine, just edited your answer `t` is missing LocationConstraint

Comment: Can you answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62718650/how-to-write-a-lambda-handler-to-send-the-data-to-elastic-search

Comment: @Nons Thanks. I added extra answer to the new question. If something, please let me know.