# How to write a lambda handler to send the data to Elasticsearch

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda

Below is the code to send the data to Elasticsearch in local

```
r = [{'Name': 'Dr. Christopher DeSimone', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Tajwar Aamir (Aamir)', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Bernard M. Aaron', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Eliana M. Aaron', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Joseph J. Aaron', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Michael R. Aaron', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Darryl H. Aarons', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. William B. Aarons', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Sirike T. Aasmaa', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Jacobo A. Abadi', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'}]
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
es.cluster.health()
es.indices.create(index='my-index', ignore=400)

for e in enumerate(r):
     es.index(index="my-index", body=e[1])
```

How to send the data to Elasticsearch of AWS using lambda handler

I have create a domain public access of Elasticsearch(t2 small) `https://search-xxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com`

How to write a lambda handler to send the data to elastic search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
session = boto3.session.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()

awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key,
                   credentials.secret_key,
                   session.region_name, 'es',
                   session_token=credentials.token)
es = Elasticsearch(
    ['https://search-xxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com'],
    http_auth=awsauth,
    use_ssl=True,
    verify_certs=True,
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection
)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    es.cluster.health()
    es.indices.create(index='my-index', ignore=400)
    r = [{'Name': 'Dr. Christopher DeSimone', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Tajwar Aamir (Aamir)', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Bernard M. Aaron', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Eliana M. Aaron', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Joseph J. Aaron', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Michael R. Aaron', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Darryl H. Aarons', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. William B. Aarons', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Sirike T. Aasmaa', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'},
 {'Name': 'Dr. Jacobo A. Abadi', 'Specialised and Location': 'Health'}]
    for e in enumerate(r):
         es.index(index="my-index", body=e[1])
```

Comment: don't we return anything? in the lambda handler

Comment: @Nons Yeah, you can return anything you want.

Answer (score 2):

To complement @jellycsc, to run your the code on lambda you will need to **bundle required packages** with your lambda code.

This means that you should prepare you **lambda deployment package** with the following python libraries:

- requests-aws4auth
- elasticsearch

AWS docs show how to do this:

- [Updating a function with additional dependencies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-dependencies)